# Wiring of pump motor

Tags: pump, motor

We are wiring a Wortex motor.

One wire is black L1 and is called "common".

The second wire is grey  L2  and called "main".

The third wire is brown and called "auxiliary".

Which one is live, which one is neutral and which one is earth ?

How do you connect it to a plug ?

Comment: I think we're gonna need some photos.  Also, is this thing something that was made on the same continent that you live on, i.e. for your market?  Or is it a trans-oceanic import?

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your post to include a picture of the manufacturer's plate of the motor (look for the little "sun over the mountains" button above the text box and upload your pic using that) and of the connections/existing wiring on the motor. Then, while you're waiting for a response, take the [tour] and read through the [help] to get a feel for the place.

Comment: Where are you in the world?  I ask because different countries use different codes in my country black is L or hot , L2 is also hot but gray is neutral  I am guessing you have 240v  single phase not sure about the aux wire we would need the model number of the pump to figure that out.

Comment: Yes, where are you on this planet, and can you post photos of the motor's nameplate?

Comment: I searched Wortex and they are based in South Africa.   Of course not sure that the OP is there, but it looks like his motor probably came from there.